# MUDAR STATUS PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tendo um problema ao mudar o status dos usuario do meu banco de dados , aquando eu vou mudar o status de algum usuario ele não aprova o usuario daquela linha e sim ultimo usuario  o que pode ser?

logado.php

```
  <?php  
                //Consulta
                $buscarusuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario");
                $buscarusuario->execute();

                //atribuindo dados á variavel
                $linha = $buscarusuario->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                //percorrendo a variavel para listar os dados
                foreach ($linha as $listar) {
                    $iduser = $listar['id'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo " <td>".$listar['id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$listar['nome']."</td>";
                    if($listar['status'] > 0 ){
                    echo "<td class='success text-success'>Aprovado 
  <form method='post' action='pg/mudastatus.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='desaprovauser' value='$iduser'>
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-success alinha-btn' name='desaprova' value='desaprovar'>Desaprovar</button>

                    </td>";
                  }else{
                    echo "<td class='danger text-danger'> Aguardando aprovação 
  <form method='post' action='pg/mudastatus.php'>
   <input type='hidden' name='aprovauser' value='$iduser'>
   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger alinha-btn' name='aprova' value='aprovar' >Aprovar</button>
</form>

                    </td>";
                  } 
  }
              ?>
```

mudastatus.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['aprova'])){

   $atualizarstatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET status=1 WHERE id='".$_POST["aprovauser"]."' ");
   $atualizarstatus->execute();
   $linha = $atualizarstatus->rowCount();

   if($linha > 0){
     header("location:../logado.php");
   }else{
    echo "Erro ao Mudar status";
   }
}elseif (isset($_POST['desaprova'])){

   $atualizarstatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET status=0 WHERE id='".$_POST["desaprovauser"]."' ");
   $atualizarstatus->execute();
   $linha = $atualizarstatus->rowCount();

   if($linha > 0){
     header("location:../logado.php");
   }else{
    echo "Erro ao Mudar status";
    header("location:../logado.php");
   }
}
```

Comment: Tá faltando um `</form>` no primeiro bloco, é bom corrigir isso antes de prosseguir com os testes. Depois dá pra enxugar bem esse código fazendo um form só para tudo e tirando os hidden, mas antes é bom você conseguir fazer funcionar do jeito que sabe, pra não complicar demais. Depois, basta tirar os campos hidden, e usar o ID dos usuários no value dos buttons aprova e desaprova.

Comment: Estou votando para fechar, pois se trata de erro de digitação, e as respostas não resolvem o problema do código, alem de conterem afirmações incorretas, atrapalhando outros usuários. Veja prova de funcionamento com nomes repetidos aqui: http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/BzkBPy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro um breve comentario sobre segurança, já que esta usando PDO e prepare... é recomendavel que vocenao passe as variaveis direto na query...

```
$atualizarstatus = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuario SET status=1 WHERE id=? ");
$atualizarstatus->execute(array($_POST["aprovauser"]));
```

Assim, você já evitaria a a injeção de sql, atraves de variaveis inseridas diretas na query.
Agora voltando a sua pergunta talvez seja que, pelo que percebi, seu codigo tera
um usuario e o botao aprovar ou desaprovar. E se tiverem mais de um, Ficaria:
Usuario1 Aprovar
Usuario2 Aprovar
Usuario3 Aprovar
Sendo esse aprovar o botao submit, voce concorda que quando eu clicar no aprovar eu vou enviar normalmente, mas como existem mais de um botao aprovar, ou seja com o mesmo nome, nao hora de pegar o valor ele nao vai saber qual voce clicou e sim pegar o ultimo botao, que é o que esta acontecendo.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: os botões estão em forms separados (deveriam estar, na verdade. parece que faltou um </form>).

Comment: Não adianta estarem em forms diferentes se a propriedade name estão iguais

Comment: Pode ter quantos name repetidos quiser em forms diferentes. Não confunda com ID. ID é um por HTML, name vc pode repetir em forms diferentes. Ou até no mesmo, desde que o backend saiba o que fazer. Inclusive, array de PHP usa o mesmo name em vários campos.

Comment: já testei nao sou tao leigo quanto acha

Comment: Não me lembro de ter comentado sobre ninguém ser ou não leigo, só apontei o engano na informação para que você tivesse oportunidade de corrigir. Apenas isso. E o codepen é apenas pra facilitar o teste pra você e quem mais tiver duvidas. http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/RRgbrd

Answer (score -2):

Você está criando vários input hidden com  mesmo name, por isso você não tem garantido qual o valor que chega no backend, tente mudar sua lógica pra cada input ter um name único.